# Redirecting “stdout” to a multiple scrolledtext widgets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, stdout

I have 3 scrolledtext Tkinter widgets and I want to redirect text to each of them independently.

First text from func1 I can print to textbox using **stdout** 
second - func2 using **stderr** but how to print as many functions as I want to multiple textboxes because if I will use **stdout** for all of this three functions it will print this 3 function to the third textbox only and will skip delegates for txt1 and txt2 but I want to make output to each textbox independent.

Take a look at the sample code:
Here 3 textboxes, 3 buttons and 3 functions which printing some text 
and each of this buttons should print text only to the corresponding textbox.

In a current way, it will print text from func1 to txt1 from func2 to txt2 and from func3 again to txt2 but it should print it to txt3.

```
class app_app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.txt1 = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self)
        self.txt1.place()

        self.txt2 = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self)
        self.txt2.place()

        self.txt3 = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self)
        self.txt3.place()

        b = tk.Button(self, text="run", command=self.func1)
        b.place()
        b1 = tk.Button(self, text="run", command=self.func2)
        b1.place()
        b2 = tk.Button(self, text="run", command=self.func3)
        b2.place() 

       sys.stdout = TextDump(self.txt1, "stdout")
       sys.stderr = TextDump(self.txt2, "stderr")
       sys.stderr = TextDump(self.txt3, "stderr")

   def func1(self):
       print("func1 print")

   def func2(self):
       print("func2 print")

   def func3(self):
       print("func3 print") 


class TextDump(object):
     def __init__(self, widget, tag="stdout"):
         self.widget = widget
         self.tag = tag

     def write(self, str):
         self.widget.configure(state="normal")
         self.widget.insert("end", str, (self.tag,))

     def flush(self):
         pass
app = app_app()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you need to use redirection here? Why not just have `func1`, `func2` and `func3` write directly to the appropriate widget?

Comment: Because without redirection all of this prints will go to console instead of textboxes

Comment: If you really want to do this via redirection, one way would be to create another `TextDump`-like class (or generalize the one you already have) that allowed writing to two (or more) `ScrolledText` widgets by having its `write()` method insert any output received into all of them...a little like what the Linux `tee` command does.

Comment: @NickPV: you missed the point of my question. Why is _redirection_ required? Why must you use the `print` statement instead of the `insert` method of the widget you want to write too? Why do you need to use the `print` statement?

Comment: @BryanOakley I need to use redirection because that's how this application is built, there function which may be callable from this UI and some function may contain printing by line and each of such line will be printing to console but I want to catch it before and append to textbox at UI so I can not do just printing in function but also should expect on some prints at third-party functions.

Comment: @BryanOakley other words I don't know how to implement this with Tkinter without redirection, I hope u understand what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion: delete TextDump.  Instead, add a write method to ScrolledText (or, probably better, a subclass thereof) and use the `file=` option of print calls.  Augmenting ScrolledText and ignoring tagging:

```
# Before app_app.
def write(self, text):
    self.insert("end", text)
ScrolledText.write = write

    # Within app_app, replace current func1/2/3 defs.
    def func1(self):
        print("func1 print", file=self.txt1)
```

For the purpose of `print`, a file is an object with a .write method.

```
>>> class Writable:
    def write(self, string): print(self, string)

>>> print('hello', file=Writable())
<__main__.Writable object at 0x000002518B289F60> hello
<__main__.Writable object at 0x000002518B289F60>      # \n
```